# C++ environment/IDE to avoid multiple reads of big data sets

Tags: c++, ide, bigdata, read-data

I am currently working on a big dataset (approximately a billion data points) and I have decided to use C++ over R in particular for convenience in memory allocation.
However, there does not seem to exist an equivalent to R Studio for C++ in order to "store" the data set and avoid to have to read the data every time I run the program, which is extremely time consuming...
What kind of techniques do C++ users use for big data in order to read the data "once for all" ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd rather write a full batch of quick unit tests operating on small amounts of data, and only use full data when necessary.

Comment: I had to look this up.  "RStudio is a free and open-source integrated development environment (IDE) for R".  To me, this does not match your "in order to 'store'" comment.  An IDE can save your program from reading the data every time you run the program?!

Comment: What I mean is that RStudio gives the opportunity to read the data once and then store it as a data frame in order to conduct a statistical analysis. Is there an equivalent for C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, i.e. load some data into memory once and use the same data (in memory) with multiple runs of your code, with possible modifications to that code, there is no such IDE, as IDE are not ment to store any data.

What you can do is first load your data into some in-memory database and write your c++ program to read data from that database instead of reading it directly from data-source in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> how avoid multiple reads of big data set.
>   What kind of techniques do C++ users use for big data in order to read
>   the data "once for all" ?

I do not know of any C++ tool with such capabilities, but I doubt that I have ever searched for one ... seems like something you might do.  Keywords appear to be 'data frame' and 'statistical analysis' (and C++).

---

If you know the 'data set' format, and wish to process raw data no more than one time, you might consider using Posix shared memory.

I can imagine that (a) the 'extremely time consuming' effort could (read and) transform the 'raw' data, and write into a 'data set' (a file) suitable for future efforts (i.e. 'once and for all').

Then (b) future efforts can 'simply' "map" the created 'data set' (a file) into the program's memory space, all ready for use with no (or at least much reduced) time consuming effort.

Expanding the memory map of your program is about using 'Posix' access to shared memory. (Ubuntu 17.10 has it, I have 'gently' used it in C++)  Terminology includes, shm_open, mmap, munmap, shm_unlink, and a few others.

From 'man mmap':

> mmap()  creates  a  new mapping in the virtual address space of the
>   calling process.  The starting address for
>          the new mapping is specified in ...

Answer (score 0):

> how avoid multiple reads of big data set. What kind of techniques do
>   C++ users use for big data in order to read the data "once for all" ?

I recently retried my hand at measuring std::thread context switch duration (on my Ubuntu 17.10, 64 bit desktop).  My app captured <30 million entries over 10 seconds of measurement time.  I also experimented with longer measurement times, and with larger captures.

As part of debugging info capture, I decided to write intermediate results to a text file, for a review of what would be input to the analysis.

The code spent only about 2.3 seconds to save this info to the capture text file.  My original software would then proceed with analysis.

But this delay to get on with testing the analysis results (> 12 sec = 10 + 2.3) quickly became tedious.

I found the analysis effort otherwise challenging, and recognized I might save time by capturing intermediate data, and thus avoiding most (but not all) of the data measurement and capture effort.  So the debug capture to intermediate file became a convenient split to the overall effort.

Part 2 of the split app reads the <30 million byte intermediate file in somewhat less 0.5 seconds, very much reducing the analysis development cycle (edit-compile-link-run-evaluate), which was was (usually) no longer burdened with the 12+ second measure and data gen.

While 28 M Bytes is not BIG data, I valued the time savings for my analysis code development effort.

---

FYI - My intermediate file contained a single letter for each 'thread entry into the critical section event'.  With 10 threads, the letters were 'A', 'B', ... 'J'.  (reminds me of dna encoding)

For each thread, my analysis supported splitting counts per thread.  Where vxWorks would 'balance' the threads blocked at a semaphore, Linux does NOT ... which was new to me.

Each thread ran a different number of times through the single critical section, but each thread got about 10% of the opportunities.

Technique: simple encoded text file with captured information ready to be analyzed.

Note:  I was expecting to test piping the output of app part 1 into app part 2.  Still could, I guess.  WIP.